# How to find a string value in a column and return values in all cells from that row?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm creating a user form that will ask for a quote number, populate the data after the quote number has been found, and update any information. The macro code I am currently using doesn't exactly work with this new user form.

[image: Search and update image]

I managed to get the textboxes to populate with the code below, but now I need it to actually update the cells if I change any text box values.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Sold As String, Soldlr As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Data Entry")

With ws
    strSearch = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Me.TextBox1.Text = aCell.Value
        Me.TextBox2.Text = aCell.Offset(, -1).Value
        Me.TextBox3.Text = aCell.Offset(, 0).Value
        Me.TextBox4.Text = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Me.TextBox5.Text = aCell.Offset(, 2).Value
        Me.TextBox6.Text = aCell.Offset(, 3).Value
        Me.TextBox7.Text = aCell.Offset(, 4).Value
        Me.TextBox8.Text = aCell.Offset(, 5).Value

    Else
        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Not Found. Try Again"

    End If

    Exit Sub
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Sold As String, Soldlr As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Data Entry")

With ws
    strSearch = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.Offset(, -1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 0).Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox5.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 3).Value = Me.TextBox6.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 4).Value = Me.TextBox7.Text
        aCell.Offset(, 5).Value = Me.TextBox8.Text

        MsgBox "Quote Number " & strSearch & " Has Been Updated"
    End If
End With

Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label8_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

Once modified, I can easily change the data in the text boxes and update the information.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to populate textboxes. Is that what you're asking how to do?

Comment: yes sir. how to populate the data on the row where the string value was found. once populated, i could change any data and press the update button to update what was changed.

Comment: On your userform code `Me.TextBoxName.Text = aCell.Value` and for a different column `Me.TextBoxDifferentName.Text = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value` etc

Comment: To write from a textbox back to the sheet, just reverse the order: `aCell.Value = Me.TextBoxName.Text` etc

Comment: Adding that gives me a (Run-time error '424': Object required) when i place it for the update button (commandButton2_Click)     :(

Comment: I got it to update, now all i need is to make the user form close and inform me the fields have been changed right after i press the update box. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence you're using Offsets so that if your number was found in B10 and you wanted C10 to go in Textbox1 you'd use

```
Me.Textbox1.Value = aCell.Offset(, 1).value
```

assuming this code lies behind the form.

Comment: Not quite. I would enter a quote number in textbox1. Assuming that quote number is on B10, i would need it to grab the values from A10:F10, and populate it into texboxs 1-6. Once populated, i could easily change the values in the text boxes and press the update button to update the cells. Mind you, button is on Sheet1 and the data is on Sheet2.

Comment: OK, well the principle is the same and you seem to have Find bit sorted out so hopefully you can adapt this for your needs.

Comment: Im new to the user forms, and barely concocted the Find code out of multiple websites. Where would your code be inserted into mine? Or do i have to modify anything?

Comment: It would go after the `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then` line. Give it a go and if you get stuck come back.

Comment: Please see the updated code above for what i need now.